# Create a encrypted SQLite database with C# EntityFramework and open with Database Browser for SQLite

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, system.data.sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I have created an encrypted SQLite database using C# EntityFramework but I'm not able to open it using DB Browser for SQLite

DB Browser for SQLite is updated at the latest version 3.11 and I'm using DB Browser (SQLCipher)

```
using System.Data.SQLite;

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{

    var conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=mySQLite.db;");

    var command = conn.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "PRAGMA key = 'password'";

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(conn);
}
```

[image: SQLCipher password request]

Does C# and related SQLCipher library use a specific configuration? How to tune C# code to open the database with DB Browser? Are there specific parameters to use (e.g. SQLite version, page size, kdf iteration, hmac and kdf algos)? I have read the [documentation](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-api/#key) but with no success.

Comment: Could you be more specific than `I'm not able to open it`? What errors and output (if any) are you getting? Have you verified that the "SQLCipher 4 defaults" settings are indeed correct?

Comment: @grooveplex I know that my question look like "i'm not able to open it" but that's the point: DB Browser doesn't open it! Pushing the OK button SQLCipher reload the same window asking me the password. The question is: does C# and related SQLCipher library use a specific configuration? I think yes but I don't know how to tune C# code to open the database with DB Browser. I have read the [documentation](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-api/#key) but with no success.

Comment: Which C# library did you use for create the sqlite database? If it is System.Data.SQLite you can't open it with SQLCipher driver.

Comment: Is [tag:db-browser-sqlite] the same as [tag:sqlite-browser]?